# env KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES not recognized by Kafka, "log.retentions.bytes" is still -1

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

We currently run Kafka container on ARM based machine (AWS Graviton).

We follow https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html to pass configuration to Kafka:

[image]

Our docker command to start Kafka is:

```sh
$ docker run -d --network mynetwork --name=kafka -p9092:9092 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092  -e KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES=500000000 linuxforhealth/kafka-alpine:2.5.0
```

However, we find that certain configurations via environment variable work, while others don't.

E.g. for `-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`, the configuratio is effective:

```sh
$ docker logs kafka | grep "advertised.listeners"
        advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

E.g. for `-e KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES=500000000`, the configuration is not effective:

```sh
$ docker logs kafka | grep "log.retention.bytes"
        log.retention.bytes = -1
```

Because of this problem, the disk ran out of space.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know where you get the guide of `KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES`, search the [doc](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html) you mentioned, not found it.

But, from the entrypoint of this image, I can see just `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` been used, no `KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it linuxforhealth/kafka-alpine:2.5.0 cat /opt/lfh/kafka/bin/lfh-kafka-start.sh
#!/bin/sh
# lfh-kafka-start.sh
# runs the Kafka Standalone server

${APP_ROOT}/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ${APP_ROOT}/kafka/config/server.properties \
    --override zookeeper.connect=${KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT} \
    --override listeners=${KAFKA_LISTENERS} \
    --override advertised.listeners=${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS} \
    --override listener.security.protocol.map=${KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP} \
    --override inter.broker.listener.name=${KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME}
```

In fact, the entrypoint uses `server.properties` to configure kafka. If I search `log.retention.bytes` in that configure, I could find next:

```
$ docker run --rm -it linuxforhealth/kafka-alpine:2.5.0 cat /opt/lfh/kafka/config/server.properties | grep -B2 log.retention.bytes

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824
```

This implies you could define your own `server.properties` to set your own value for `log.retention.bytes`, then mount it to container when start your container, something like next:

```
-v `pwd`/server.properties:/opt/lfh/kafka/config/server.properties linuxforhealth/kafka-alpine:2.5.0
```

Comment: My understanding from the doc is: for every setting in the properties file, there is a corresponding environment variable, with a naming convention as described in the screenshot in my original post.

Comment: If you use `docker run --rm -it confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0 cat /etc/confluent/docker/kafka.properties.template` to have a look, you could see the image mentioned in doc really have something like `{% set kafka_props = env_to_props('KAFKA_', '', exclude=excluded_props) -%}` to get all `KAFKA prefix` environment value and set them to configure. But why you think your image `linuxforhealth/kafka-alpine:2.5.0` could automatically have this effect? You used a image not same as the image mentioned in Doc... This is not a kafka feature, it's the image owner did some trick for it...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I thought it's a Kafka feature with or without dockerization. I don't find any other ARM64 based image other than this one. I'd love to use the official image if they provide ARM64 based image.